# Deleting rows from multiple tables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a row of nested table, each with an individual ID and multiple rows. In the first table (blank0) I have the action deleteLink

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $("#blank0 .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
       var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
           tr.remove();
       });
       return false;
   }); 
});
```

This deletes the selected row as expected. What I want it to do is to delete the same row across all my tables. For example if I click the 3rd delete button, I would want it to delete the 3rd row on blank0 through to blank9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd give all the tables a common class and use the `rowIndex` property to filter out the `<tr>`s.

```
$('.blank').on('click', '.deleteLink', function () {
  var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prop('rowIndex');
  $('.blank tr').filter(function () {
    return this.rowIndex === rowIndex;
  }).remove();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/yugurekiri/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks but I need the other tables to remove their relative <tr> also. The other tables are blank0 blank1 .... blank10

Comment: I'm suggesting you add a common class of `blank` so you don't need to query them all individually. So do like `<table id="blank0" class="blank">`, `<table id="blank1" class="blank">`, etc.